# Ignore property when converting object to json string

Tags: json, wpf, serialization, properties, odata

So i have a REST API that works with a JSON based on OData exchange. In a OData type there is a ID property i want to read so i can do some checking on it. However when i want to write back to the webserver the ID property must not be present in the response JSON string. So it has to be a write-only property, but simply changing a property to write-only prevents be to check what the value is of that property.

For example, i create a new product:

```
Public Class Product
  Public property ID as integer
  Public property Title as string
End class
```

GET response:

```
{
  "ID" = 1,
  "Title" = "Cool product!"
}
```

POST Wrong:

```
{
  "ID" = 1, <---- ignore this value
  "Title" = "Cool product! Changed!"
}
```

POST Should be:

```
{
  "Title" = "Cool product! Changed!"
}
```

The webserver uses OData

Using the attribute `JsonIgnore`doesn't fix it because the value of the REST response isn't serialized then.

This is for WPF and not ASP.Net

Comment: Are you using Json.NET to serialize `Product`?

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.NET supports [conditional property serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) using a method that returns a `bool` and has the same name as the property with a ShouldSerialize prefix:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeId() => false;

}
```

Comment: Thnx, will try it tomorrow!